Issue with Nginx reverse proxy (CONNECTION_REFUSED)
I have set up an EC2 (ubuntu). I have my front end being served by Nginx and my backend running with pm2. I know my backend is up an running since I curl it from the ubuntu server and I responds, furthermore I opened the port in the security group for testing purposes and sending a request from postman works.
My understanding is that I need to set up a reverse proxy so Nginx routes the calls from the front end for a specific path (/api/ for instance) to a different address (my backend).
I also understand that since everything is running in the same server, I should call my backend on http://localhost:4011 instead of exposing my backend and calling it through the public IP in the same fashion that curl localhost:4011 works from the terminal.
But I am unable to make it work, every time the front makes a request to http://127.0.0.1:4011 the response is:
http://127.0.0.1:4011/api/authentication/userLogin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
This is my Nginx configuration:
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        return 301 htps://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        #if ($host = helpful-thinking.online) {
        #       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        #} # managed by Certbot




        root /var/www/html/mysite;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
                }

        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4011;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

        }

I don't know if this is due to a misunderstanding on how this should work or if I am missing something else.
Thank you in advance!
EDIT
I did not understand how the reverse proxy is intended to work.
My issue was that I was expecting the client to call localhost and nginx to proxy that to the backend. I just had to modify my front so the requests were pointing to my domain and THEN route them to my backend via nginx reverse proxy.
So instead of calling http://127.0.0.1:4011
I should call https://example.com:443
And then nginx will proxy the request to my backend.

your Nginx is listening on 443 when you are requesting 4011.

Thanks, it was a skill issue. After some additional research now I understand that I need to make the client call my domain over port 443 and proxy that request to my backend on 4011.
